# As to differentiate the users with TouchID

Tags: xcode, touch-id

It would like to know if I obtain to differentiate which user this informing the fingerprint, as well as Apple obtains!

```
 [self evaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics
         localizedReason:@"" reply:^(BOOL success, NSError *authenticationError){
        if (success) {
              //Code Here
        else {
              //Code Here 
         }
    }];
```

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Any discoveries since you asked the question?

Comment: I walked searching, but I did not find nothing nothing

Answer (score 5):

It's impossible.

The SDK only give access to validation success or failure status, nothing more.

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/LocalAuthentication/Reference/LocalAuthentication_Framework/index.html

The reason behind that is that the Fingerprint is stored in a safe location of the A7/8 chip, not even accessible to the iOS kernel, which only give access to this very high success/failure information.